# Database Caching in Yii2 Starter Kit

Tags: php, yii2

When I changed the environment in the project made from [this template](https://github.com/trntv/yii2-starter-kit/) from **dev** to **prod**, it starts to cache the content of database. Changes made in database does not have effect. It only takes effect after I changed back the environment to **dev**. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This line](https://github.com/trntv/yii2-starter-kit/blob/master/common/config/base.php#L64) enables schema caching on production environment. This is desired effect.

You can change the duration of cache (default is 3600 s):

```
'schemaCacheDuration' => 300, // sets schema cache to 5 minutes
'queryCacheDuration' => 120, // sets query cache to 2 minutes
```

If you want to flush the cache (for example after making changes to DB) you can call this console command (modify path for your system):

```
path/to/yii cache/flush-all
```